# CS50 Plurality – having trouble understanding why candidate_count is used

Tags: cs50

I'm trying to understand why candidate_count is used instead of voter count in CS50's Plurality (week 3). Below is my code.

If we imagine we have three candidates (Alice, Bob, Charlie) and every time we iterate through the bool function or the print_winner function, would we not miss out on counting votes if we had something like 10 voters? According to my understanding, 'i' would only ever iterate 3 times. I'm having a conceptual issue in understanding why we wouldn't use voter_count instead in the print winner function at the bottom.

I'm still trying to refine my code a bit, so parts may still be buggy. I'm just looking for some help in clarifying the logic in this problem.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates (number of arguments - 1 because the first arg is going to be plurality)
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1]; // 
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int maxvotes = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > maxvotes)
        {
            maxvotes = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        printf("the winner is %s\n!", candidates[i].name);
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand *what* we're looping through. `candidate_count` is used to loop through `candidates` which is an array with **`candidate_count` number of elements**.

Consider this simple array-

```c
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

We would loop through this using-

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("value at index %d is %d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

notice the part `i < 5`. Why 5? Well because that's the length of the array `arr`, anything more and we'd be reading out of bounds, anything less and we would not be reading the entire `arr`.

Now replace `arr` with `candidates`, which is also an array and replace `5` with `candidate_count`, which is obviously the **length of said array**.

The loops in `vote` or `print_winner` functions do not "count votes", they **iterate through the array of candidates**. That's the purpose of those loops. Hence, to iterate through an array, we must use `index < length_of_array`. That's exactly what it does.

Just to address the concern of "where does it count votes then?". Let's look at `vote` real quick-

```c
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function is triggered after user input, so let's say the user is **asked for a name** - they pick some name, assume this name matches with a candidate. So `vote` is called, it **iterates through the array of candidates**. Why does it iterate? It needs to **find the candidate who has the same name** as the name just provided by the user.

So the purpose of this loop, is to iterate through the array `candidates`, and the purpose of the code *within this loop* is to compare the names of each candidate to the name provided by the user. If it matches, it *increments the votes of that candidate*.

This line- `candidates[i].votes++;`

*That* is where the `votes` are counted. It's a simple as incrementing a counter.

Imagine a real life scenario, you're the program. The candidates are all standing in a line (an array). Each candidate starts with 0 cards (votes). Assume none of them have the same name.

- A user tells you that they wanna vote for candidate foo (just a name).
- You then go to that line of candidates. You start by the first candidate and ask them "what is your name?".
- The candidate tells you their name.

  - If their name matches with the name the user gave you, this is it, you give them a card representing the vote. Now they have 1 more card than they had before
  - If their name does not match, you move to the next candidate and repeat.

  But where do you stop? Simple, you stop before the last candidate. How many iterations could this take maximum? `candidate_count`, i.e the number of candidates standing in that line. So, worst case scenario, the person you're looking for is at the very end of the line, so you have to ask `candidate_count` number of people before finally finding the one you're looking for. *Traversing an array*.
- In the end, you just count how many cards each candidate has to realize who's the winner. (`.votes`)

The `print_winner` function should do the same thing. Though your code seems a bit crooked.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    if (candidates[i].votes > maxvotes)
    {
        maxvotes = candidates[i].votes;
    }
}
```

This loop is the equivalent of going through the whole line of candidates, asking each one how many cards (votes) they have and finding out who has the maximum number of cards (votes).

But you also need to ask the name of the person with the `maxvotes`! That's what you're looking for.

But you completely ditch the `maxvotes` you just calculated later, you never use it.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    printf("the winner is %s\n!", candidates[i].name);
}
```

That loop will print the name of every single `candidate`. It's the equivalent of going through the whole line of candidates (array), asking each one "what is your name?" and shouting out "The winner is [their name]!". But that's not true!

You should store the name of the candidate, as well as `maxvotes` and then print it after the first loop-

```c
string winner_name;

...

for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    if (candidates[i].votes > maxvotes)
    {
        maxvotes = candidates[i].votes;
        winner_name = candidates[i].name;
    }
}
printf("the winner is %s\n!", candidates[i].name);
```

Of course, this does not take care of multiple winners, what if 2 candidates have the same number of votes? That's something you'll have to try yourself.

But I hope this answers your question about the confusion.